# Is there any way to restrict my access to a file which I have uploaded?

Tags: documentum

I have uploaded a document lets say a.txt, in some folder. It was uploaded successfully, however I can not see it there.

There are multiple other files which I uploaded earlier and I can see them lets say b.txt.

When I try to upload the file a.txt again its showing an error that the file already exists there, and showing me the object ID. I checked the Object ID in the backend and found that it points to a.txt itself.

I also compared the properties of a.txt and b.txt both are exactly same.

Can anyone suggest if any other thing can restrict my access to the document?

Comment: Check ACL assigned to that document if your user has at least READ permission.

Comment: As I checked, dm_owner has the full access to the file. And as I have uploaded it, I should be able to view, update and delete it

Comment: Thanks cgrim for the response. The issue was because of the search was not working properly and the file was there. Also the file was an email attachment and so we were unable to upload the same email twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found I later, the issue persists only when you upload emails.
When I uploaded an email it went through successfully, however if I tried to upload the same email again it won't allow it.

We can fix that by changing some configuration on server however its implemented so as to make these email contents searchable.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the CURRENT label on the file version got removed for some reason. See if you can find all the versions of that file.

Comment: I checked the current version of the file. Its still says CURRENT.

Comment: When you check permissions, don't check dm_owner permissions. Check the effective permissions at the top of the ACL screen. I don't have access to documentum right now, else would have provided a screen shot. You need at least effective browse permissions to see the file. Other option is to delete the file using api. Does the i_chronicle_id and r_object_id match for the document? Meaning, is there only one version or multiple versions for the object?